# Find the possible equations of planes containing a line

Tags: linear-algebra

If I had a line in $R^3$ that had all its points described by $P =\begin{pmatrix} a\\ b\\ c \end{pmatrix}+\lambda \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\\z \end{pmatrix}$ where $a, b,$ and $c$ are constants, what would be the general equation for a plane that passes through it?

Comment: There are infinitely many planes that contain that line.

Comment: Is there a general equation however, one that just produces a plane containing it for some value K?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{pmatrix} a\\ b\\ c \end{pmatrix}+\lambda \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\\z \end{pmatrix}+\mu \begin{pmatrix}d \\ e\\ f\end{pmatrix}$$

where $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}d \\ e\\ f\end{pmatrix}$ are not parallel to each other.

Answer (score 1):

A plane $\epsilon$ is uniquely determined by a normal vector $n$ and an arbitrary point $P$ lying on this plane via
$$\epsilon := \{\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3: \langle \textbf{x}-P, n \rangle = 0\}.$$

Since you know, that your line must lie in your plane, you can simply choose your $P = \begin{pmatrix}
 a \\
 b \\
 c
\end{pmatrix}$ as described above and you only need to find out all the possibilities for your normal vector $n$. But these are exactly the solutions of the linear equation
$$\Big\langle \lambda \begin{pmatrix}
 x \\
 y \\
 z
\end{pmatrix},n \Big\rangle = 0 \;\Leftrightarrow \; (x,y,z) \begin{pmatrix}
 n_x \\
 n_y \\
 n_z
\end{pmatrix} = 0 \; \Leftrightarrow \; xn_x + yn_y + zn_z = 0. $$

If you need an explicit equation which describes your plane you can also (after finding a normal vector $n$) calculate $d:= \langle n,P \rangle$ to write your plane as
$$\epsilon =  \{ \textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3 : \langle \textbf{x},n\rangle = d \}.$$